# PHP: how to create date before the Epoch (1970) using Date instead of DateTime?

Tags: php, date, datetime, timestamp, epoch

In my PHP script I've got a function handling birthdays like so:

```
$dateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $time);
```

The problem is that this returns `false` with negative $time numbers (i.e. dates before 1-1-1970). In the PHP docs there's a comment saying that indeed

> Note that the U option does not support negative timestamps (before
>   1970). You have to use date for that.

I'm unsure of how to use Date to get the same result as `DateTime::createFromFormat()` gives though. Does anybody have a tip on how to do this?

Comment: `$dateTime = new DateTime("@$time");` should do the trick

Answer (score 3):

If you just need to format a UNIX timestamp as a readable date, `date` is simple to use:

```
// make sure to date_default_timezome_set() the timezone you want to format it in
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', -12345);
```

If you want to create a `DateTime` instance from a negative UNIX timestamp, you can use this form of the regular constructor:

```
$datetime = new DateTime('@-12345');
```